# Buildozer fails, I think I need the prerequisite 32 bit libraries, but Fedora uses yum, not apt-get

Tags: android, python-2.7, fedora, kivy

I'm trying to compile a fairly simple kivy application into an android app. The kivy application is written in python2.7. It compiles the application, but then fails. Here's the log: http://pastebin.com/Q60ErXxf

From what I've seen, I'm missing some 32-bit libraries that kivy and buildozer require. Here's the page with the apt-get instructions: http://python-for-android.readthedocs.org/en/latest/prerequisites/

However, Fedora uses yum, and I've tried yum install for these packages, but to no avail. What are the packages that Fedora needs for this to work?

However, I'm not totally sure this is what the problem is, so if you understand something in the log, please enlighten me. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are missing some 32bit libraries, you could try the advice on this question to find the ones you need. https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/9556/how-do-i-install-32bit-libraries-on-a-64-bit-fedora/

Odds are that you only need the i386 version of libc6-dev-i386 lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6 zlib1g-dev

Comment: Did you use the full ia32-libs equivalent command, or a subset?