# Buildozer Error: Could not create service of type FileHasher using GradleUserHomeScopeServices.createCachingFileHasher()

Tags: android, python, kivy, kivy-language, buildozer

In order to create the .apk file that will be able to be run on an android phone, I decided to use the kivy virtual machine to run buildozer on Linux. I was able to setup the buildozer.spec and the main.py, but when I ran `buildozer android debug deploy run`, it gave me this error message

[Error Message](https://docs.google.com/document/d/16S16GTrEU_McSc3j33LxBr-Cx0i7abrxO6c3oZXfltk/edit?usp=sharing)

This is the buildozer.spec file

[Buildozer.spec](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UAHekPUatAOrdIU_zFRwoPWgQKd-d0L3QsRXOr2Lo4Q/edit?usp=sharing)

And this is the main.py

```
 import kivy

 from kivy.app import App

 import cv2

 from kivy.uil.label import Label



 class SimpleKivy(object):

 def build(self):

    return Label(text="Hello World!")



  if __name__ == "__main__":

  SimpleKivy().run()
```

Comment: Kivy a nice framework to make apk from python,I work with it over fedora and I make MathFun [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ta3lem4all.com.mathfun) ,I think your problem with `Buildozer.spec`

Comment: Yeah, I used the kivy VM found on the website that runs Ubuntu. Could  you please elaborate eon what exactly you think the issue is with the buildozer.spec file?

Comment: I work with it from along time ,but I think your errors from buildozer as it is a responsible about whole process

Comment: So should I perhaps try and change to fedora?

Comment: May be, Fedora will be more suitable to kivy framework.

Comment: Also you can check this,it may be help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775111/python-kivy-why-is-buildozer-failing-to-push-program-to-my-phone?rq=1

Comment: I changed the version to Fedora and got this error:https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Le58Fe9Vjh6BfLeLJCA7mqmieUGJ3j3ifCoPiVyRH3g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: please read this carefully `# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2`

Comment: changing the log_level to 2 resulted in the same error